# Secure traffic between pods in cluster

Tags: security, ssl, kubernetes

In some hosting environments/configurations, the network traffic between pods (applications) may traverse the public Internet. As a result, I'd like to secure the communication between the pods.

For example, I have the following structure:

Service_A - edge service in my product and provides access to my API to external users via public IP.

Service_B and Service_C - microservices that has ClusterIP(s).

As I understand I can secure traffic user<-> Service_A by using Ingress controller with ssl certificate.

But how should I secure Service_A<->Service_B communication? Create additional ingress services to wrap microservices? Are there any best practices for such cases?

One detail: microservices use gRPC for communication.

Thanks

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: This question is about "software tools commonly used by programmers", namely Kubernetes. There are a lot of other networking questions in the kubernetes tag, so this doesn't seem out of line to me.

Answer (score 9):

A simple, generic solution that I like is to run a reverse-proxy (such as nginx) in each pod. All of your app containers will listen on localhost or unix sockets, and the ssl proxy will terminate external HTTPS connections. This makes it easy to audit your SSL config across all your apps, since every connection is terminated by the same nginx config.

Certificate distribution is the primary challenge with this approach. For external services, you can use LetsEncrypt to generate certs. For internal services, you'll need a private CA that is trusted by your ssl-proxy. You can mount the CA cert in a config-map at runtime. You'd then generate a cert per app or per-pod, and mount that as a Secret consumed in the ssl-proxy container.

If this sounds like too much work, you might want to look at https://github.com/istio/istio, which aims to automate the cluster CA role, and the provision of per-pod certificates.

Comment: Istio sounds like a perfect fit for the problem